# Get time ago from an date that is saved as a string. ruby rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, date, ruby-on-rails-5

Im still kinda new.

I saved an date from json data, i saved it in my database as an string. Here by my quistion:

Does anybody have a good idea of how i can calculate how many **minutes,hours or days AGO** the date is?

***"2019-12-09T11:06:37.000Z"***

This is what normal dates look like in my database: ***2019-12-10 18:28:38.249866***

Comment: Do you know the time zone you are saving the time in?

Comment: It seems like the root problem is that you put the dates in your database in the wrong format. Why not fix that problem first?

Comment: How can i save it in the right format when the numbers aint even the same. The date is way different then mine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The easiest way if you want to avoid doing a bunch of math is by using [ActiveSupport::Duration](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/ActiveSupport/Duration.html).

```
irb(main):001:0> time = Time.zone.parse("2019-12-09T11:06:37.000Z")
=> Mon, 09 Dec 2019 11:06:37 UTC +00:00
irb(main):002:0> duration = ActiveSupport::Duration.build(Time.zone.now - time)
=> 1 day, 11 hours, 10 minutes, and 31.248518 seconds
irb(main):003:0> duration.parts
=> {:days=>1, :hours=>11, :minutes=>10, :seconds=>31.248518}
```

Comment: Saving what is obviously is a ISO8601 timestamp in a string column seems pretty stupid when pretty much every db in existence has real date/time columns.